# Angular 1.x - adding event listeners to elements inside custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a directive in the angular app, where I send text from the backend, and I am just displaying it in the frontend like this:

```
<article-text ng-bind-html="article.text" class="article-text"></article-text>
```

Since, this is an ionic app, I need to add to every `a tag` in the text a click event listener, so that I can open urls in the system browser instead of inside the application:
That would be the on click function:

```
openExternal(elem) {
    window.open(elem.href, "_system");
    return false;
}
```

But, not sure how to get all the elements inside the directive and add event listeners?

This is was my attempt:

```
.directive('articleText', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      var links = element[0].querySelectorAll('a');
      angular.forEach(links, function(link) {
        link.bind('click', function() {
          window.open(this.href, "_system");
          return false;
         });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

But, that is not working. I get an empty array for:

```
var links = element[0].querySelectorAll('a');
console.log(links);
```

> NodeList[0] 
>    length : 0

Answer (score 0):

> I get an empty array for:
>
> ```
> var links = element[0].querySelectorAll('a');
> console.log(links);
> ```

The selector query finds no `<a>` tags because the html has not yet been rendered when the selector query executes.

Use [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) to wait for the arrival of html data from the server.

```
angular.module("myApp").directive('articleText', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      //USE $watch
      scope.$watch(attrs.ngBindHtml, function(value) {
        var links = element.find('a');
        console.log(links);
        links.on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.open(this.href, "_system");
            return false;
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/UulSEZzeFknQDQ95W2J1?p=preview)